# Boto DynamoDB not supporting dictionaries?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto

I have the following Python code that tries to store an item into DynamoDB. While everything works fine for strings, etc.. it fails when I try to add a dictionary.

The table has one primary hash-key called "Parameter"

```
import boto
from boto.dynamodb import connect_to_region

conn = connect_to_region('eu-west-1')

table = conn.get_table('my-table')

item_dict = {
    'Parameter': 'dbparams',
    'Value': {
        'host': 'myserver',
        'user': 'myusername',
        'password': 'mypass',
        'port': '5555',
    },
}

item = table.new_item(attrs=item_dict)
item.put()
```

This results in the following error:

```
boto.dynamodb.exceptions.DynamoDBValidationError: DynamoDBValidationError: 400 Bad Request
{'__type': 'com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException', 'message': 'Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes'}
```

What is the correct way to do this? I couldn't find an example in the Boto docs either.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to execute the code using **boto + dynamodb2** library. You seemed to have an *extra* comma after 'port': '5555' - you can get rid of that. I have attached a screen shot of the results - so you can see what I got. Hopefully this helps. Here is a link in case you want to use the library http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/dynamodb2_tut.html.

```
import boto.dynamodb2
from boto.dynamodb2.table import Table

#Put in your connection code here and get access to the connection and table objects.
#Once you have your table object..... execute put

table.put_item(data={'Id': 323,
'Parameter': 'dbparams',
'Value': {
        'host': 'myserver',
        'user': 'myusername',
        'password': 'mypass',
        'port': '5555'
    }
})
```

[image]